# TypeError: 'HMAC' object is not callable

Tags: python, hmac

When passing the following

```
hmac.new(secretkey.encode(), sig1.encode(), sha1)
```

I'm receiving the following error

> TypeError: 'HMAC' object is not callable

I'm sure this is probably basic for most but I am just getting to grips with python and it's causing a bit of a headache.

Can someone help explain or solve the issue

More info as requested

```
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=something"  # url = "https://google.com"
realurl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"
http_method = "GET"
oauth_consumer_key = "removed"
oauth_token = "removed"
oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1"
oauth_timestamp = "1430882576"
oauth_nonce = "pISS1c"
oauth_version = "1.0"
oauth_signature = "removed"
oauth_consumer_secret_key = "removed"


class TwitterModel:
    def SignitureGenerator():

    from urllib.parse import quote
    import binascii
    import hmac
    from hashlib import sha1

    secretkey = quote(oauth_consumer_secret_key, '')+"&"+quote(oauth_token_secret, '')

    sig1 = realurl+"&oauth_consumer_key="+oauth_consumer_key+"&oauth_nonce="+oauth_nonce+"&26oauth_signature_method="+oauth_signature_method+"&oauth_timestamp="+oauth_timestamp+"&oauth_token="+oauth_token+"&oauth_version="+oauth_version

    sig1 = "GET&"+quote(sig1, '')

    hashkey = hmac.new(secretkey.encode(), sig1.encode(), sha1)

    return hashkey
```

*Traceback*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 841, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
 File "/var/www/projects/twitter/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 867, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
 TypeError: 'HMAC' object is not callable
```

Comment: Need a bit more of your code... have you reassigned `hmac` or directly imported it?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `hmac.new(secretkey.encode(), sig1.encode(), sha1)()`?

Comment: Updated with full code @Jkdc

Comment: Still not your real code, `return` statement without any function body?

Comment: Updates with full model code

Comment: The code looks fine, whoever is receiving the `hashkey` returned from `SignitureGenerator` is actually trying to call it, which is incorrect.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The controller is just returning the model results and the router is returning the controllers results. Is there a way I can debug this better?

Comment: @cusackBOOM Check or post the the entire traceback, it will tell you which part is trying to call `hashkey`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems by appending .digest() to the hmac.new seems to have cleared up the issue.

```
hashkey = hmac.new(secretkey.encode(), sig1.encode(), sha1).digest()
```